# Continue zip(), if one source is completed

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux, reactor

I have some troubles with .zip() operator.

Let me simplify my problem on a small example.

```
    Flux<Integer> flux1 = Flux.just(9, 8, 3, -2);
    Flux<Integer> flux2 = Flux.just(7);
    Flux<Integer> flux3 = Flux.just(6, 5, 4, -4);

    List<Flux<Integer>> list1 = Arrays.asList(flux1, flux2, flux3);

    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    Set<Integer> list = Flux.zip(list1, objects -> {
        boolean setChanged = false;
        for (Object o : objects) {
            Integer i = (Integer) o;

            if (set.size() < 5 || i > set.last()) {
                setChanged = true;
                set.add(i);
                if (set.size() > 5) {
                    set.pollLast();
                }
            }
        }

        return setChanged;
    }).takeWhile(val -> val)
            .then(Mono.just(set))
            .block();

    System.out.println(list);
```

Here I have 3 different sources(they are sorted descending by default, and the number of them could be much bigger), and I want to get from them a collection of 5 elements sorted descending. Unfortunately, I can't just use concat() or merge() operators, because sources in a real life can be really big, but I need only small amount of elements.

I am expecting [9, 8, 7, 6, 5] here, but one of the sources is completed after first iteration of zipping.

Could you please suggest how I can get around with this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use merge? This seems like a typical use case - I'd just merge all those fluxes then do `mergedFlux.take(5).sort(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collectList()` or similar. There's no issues with using it on a very large, or infinite flux - prefetch aside, it will just take the results it needs and then cancel. That's one of the big advantages using reactive streams in the first place, you can deal with streams as big as you like (to infinity if necessary) without holding it all in memory.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Well, in case of using merge() how you suggested I get [9, 8, 7, 3, -2] as a result. So, it seems like we are iterating through the whole first Flux, and then start to iterate the second. It's not appropriate for me, because in my case all sources are using DB, and if flux1 have > 1,000,000 elements it will take a lot of time even if I need only 50 elements. Maybe I misunderstand the concept of reactive streams, and there is an another approach?

Comment: No, `merge()` will take the first results available from any flux (see the marble diagram [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-). The behaviour you're seeing there is a side effect of using `Flux.just()` - all the elements are immediately available simultaneously so the result here is kind of undefined. Or have I missed something, and you don't just want the first 5 elements emitted from any of the fluxes?

Comment: Thank you for diagram, now I understand better. But is there any way to avoid this aside affect and guarantee that my final result data will be consistent? In my case user can request 100 elements as well as only 5.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean - the consistency is almost never going to be guaranteed in a "real" scenario that returns a flux, because it entirely depends on when the elements are emitted (which in turn depends on which network calls or other non-blocking operations just so happen to complete first.) Or do you not want the first values emitted across all fluxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the reduce operation

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        Flux<Integer> flux1 = Flux.just(9, 8, 3, -2);
        Flux<Integer> flux2 = Flux.just(7, 0, -2, 4,3,2,2,1);
        Flux<Integer> flux3 = Flux.just(6, 5, 4, -4);

        var k = 5;
        List<Flux<Integer>> publishers = List.of(flux1, flux2, flux3);
        var flux = Flux.merge(publishers)
                .log()
                .limitRate(2)
                .buffer(2)
                .reduce((l1, l2) -> {
                    System.out.println(l1);
                    System.out.println(l2);

                    return Stream.concat(
                            l1.stream(),
                            l2.stream()
                    ).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .limit(k)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                })
                .log();

        StepVerifier.create(flux)
                .expectNext(List.of(9,8,7,6,5))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
```

You can fetch data in chunks and compare them to find the top K elements.

In a sequential case it will fetch a new batch, compare it to the current top k result and return a new topk like in the example above (PriorityQueue may work better for sorting if k is big).
If you're using parallel schedulers and batches are fetched in parallel, then it can compare them with each other independently that should be a bit faster.
Also you have full control over the fetched data via rateLimit, buffer, delayElements, etc